# Error 102 chrome

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, connection-issues, chrome-for-android

I have a micromax a102 and when ever I try to visit a page which I was able to visit few days ago like Google weblite I get error 102 or connection refused on pretty much every where a few points you should read before helping me

1 yes I have root i using king root

2 I have no proxy and no static IP address

3 I don't use a VPN

4 all other devices work with out a error

5 I don't have any kind of adblock

6 tried to reboot and quick reboot 2 times

7 yes some sites works but not all other websites though they work fine on other devices

8 all used devices are on same WiFi and work fairly well

9 all apps seems to work fairly well

10 checked on chrome and default browser and Firefox